# Swift/Widget Extension - Time update every second

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

This is my first post, so let me know if any more info is needed.

I am creating a widget that will display the current time for two locations at the same time.

This is the current code I have:

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct TimeWidgetView: View {
    var localTime: String
    var foreignTime: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 16) {
            VStack{
                Text("Local Time")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                
                Text(localTime)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
            }
            
            VStack{
                Text("China Time")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                
                Text(foreignTime)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TimeWidget: Widget {
    private let kind: String = "TimeWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: TimeProvider()) { entry in
            TimeWidgetView(localTime: entry.localTime, foreignTime: entry.foreignTime)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Time Widget")
        .description("Displays local time and China time.")
    }
}

struct TimeProvider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> TimeEntry {
        TimeEntry(localTime: "00:00", foreignTime: "00:00")
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (TimeEntry) -> Void) {
        let entry = TimeEntry(localTime: "12:34", foreignTime: "23:34")
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<TimeEntry>) -> Void) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let localTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        localTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let localTime = localTimeFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
        
        let foreignTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        foreignTimeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Shanghai") // Set time zone to China
        foreignTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let foreignTime = foreignTimeFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
        
        let entry = TimeEntry(localTime: localTime, foreignTime: foreignTime)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct TimeEntry: TimelineEntry {
    var date: Date = Date()
    var localTime: String
    var foreignTime: String
}

struct TimeWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimeWidgetView(localTime: "12:34:56", foreignTime: "23:34:45")
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
}
```

When I run the app/widget from Xcode, it displays the correct time, but the time doesn't change.. I don't understand how can I accomplish this.

How can I make it update every second so it works as a digital clock?

EDIT: I may found a solution, but not sure if this is a good way to go (thinking about battery life):

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<TimeEntry>) -> Void) {
        var entries: [TimeEntry] = []
        
        // Use a Timer to update the widget every half second as a clock
        let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        for second in 0...59 {
            let currentDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(second))
            
            let localTime = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
            
            let foreignTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
            foreignTimeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Shanghai") // Set time zone to China
            foreignTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            let foreignTime = foreignTimeFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
            
            let entry = TimeEntry(date: currentDate, localTime: localTime, foreignTime: foreignTime)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

Comment: Widgets have a "budget" you can only call `getTimeline` about every 15 minutes in the best of circumstances. Apple can throttle this as much as the want based on many factors. `Text` with `style` offer a few alternatives for second updates but it is very limited but it might works for you if this is your true UI. you can work your way through the "Widget Code Along" for more info.

Comment: As @loremipsum already mentioned, you have almost no possibility to tell iOS to update your widget. iOS manages all this internally and will update the widgets every few minutes. You can just tell iOS that your data changed since the last update, and iOS decides when it will display the new data.

**TL;DR:** you cannot update a widget every second, since Apple doesn't allow that.

Comment: @loremipsum Check my edit, I found a solution, but not sure if this is a good one?

Comment: @beeef Check my edit, I found a solution, but not sure if this is a good one?

Comment: That timer isn’t doing anything… I don’t know where you found that but it serves no purpose. There is no way around the budget. A widget is like a GIF each entry in like an image that makes the gif. You have 1 minute’s work of entries there.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the official documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date

I think if you try to bypass the limitations, you may only get "punished" and your widget will be updated even less frequently.

I also checked if it's possible to implement animations within your widget, so that you can implement a moving clock hand that basically moves by itself without manually updating it every second, but that also doesn't work since animations are not available within WidgetKit. So yeah, I think what you want to achieve is just not possible.